# Concatenate encoded columns to original data frame using Scikit-learn and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to encode all the textual data in a `.csv` file to numeric using Python's Scikit-learn. I am using `LabelEncoder` and `OneHotEncoder` on the columns which are of datatype `object`. I am wondering how to concatenate the new encoded columns with the original dataframe - `df` in this case. I am new to this and would really appreciate some help. Here's my code:

```
"""Encode all columns with type Object using LabelEncoder"""
columnsToEncode=df.select_dtypes(include=[object])

labelEncoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df_2 = columnsToEncode.apply(labelEncoder.fit_transform)

"""Now encode using OneHotEncoder"""
oneHotEncoder = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
df_3=oneHotEncoder.fit_transform(df_2)
```

Comment: So you want your dataframe to have the actual textual data as well as the encoded data ? Any particular reason you want to concatenate/merge the encoded columns/data with the original dataframe ?

Comment: @asimo I want to replace the actual textual data columns with the encoded data for applying K-means clustering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly here, you are looking to encode the columns and have them back in a dataframe format.
One way of doing this could be :

Convert your df into a matrix.

```
df_array = df.as_matrix(columns=['A','B','C'])
```

Perform the encoding:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing  
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()    
for i in range(len(df.columns)):   
     df_array[:,i] = le.fit_transform(df_array[:,i])
```

For the OneHotEncoder :

```
enc = OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(df_array)      

OHE_array=enc.transform(df_array).toarray()
```

However, this OHE can increase the dimensionality in a big way.
So you may want to perform  PCA or some sort of dimensionality reduction techniques to apply computationally feasible algorithms.

If you want it back in the dataframe format:

```
 newdf=pd.DataFrame(df_array, columns=['A','B','C'])
```

Comment: Thank you @asimo. That was helpful but I want to use `OneHotEncoder` as well. How can I do that and merge to one data frame at the end?

Comment: Just edited my earlier answer to include the OneHotEncoder

Comment: @asimo I don't think this is the correct way because after one-hot encoding the number of columns would be equal the number of categorical variables you have in the data frame. Then how could you only specify three-column name? in case you have 100 distinct values what would you do?

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of methods to do this. Assuming you want to encode the independent variables you can use pd.get_dummies with the drop_first=True included. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a data of independent variables X for the example
X = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['China', 'India', 'USA', 'Indonesia', 'Brasil'],
                   'Continent': ['Asia', 'Asia', 'North America', 'Asia', 'South America'],
                   'Population, M': [1403.5, 1324.2, 322.2, 261.1, 207.6]})

print(X)

# Encode
columnsToEncode=X.select_dtypes(include=[object]).columns
X = pd.get_dummies(X, columns=columnsToEncode, drop_first=True)

print(X)

# X prior to encoding
       Continent    Country  Population, M
0           Asia      China         1403.5
1           Asia      India         1324.2
2  North America        USA          322.2
3           Asia  Indonesia          261.1
4  South America     Brasil          207.6

# X after encoding
   Population, M  Continent_North America  Continent_South America  \
0         1403.5                        0                        0   
1         1324.2                        0                        0   
2          322.2                        1                        0   
3          261.1                        0                        0   
4          207.6                        0                        1   

   Country_China  Country_India  Country_Indonesia  Country_USA  
0              1              0                  0            0  
1              0              1                  0            0  
2              0              0                  0            1  
3              0              0                  1            0  
4              0              0                  0            0
```

Comment: Thanks @KRKirov. I didn't quite understand what `drop_first=True` does. Could you please explain that?

Comment: drop_first=True removes one column from each categorical feature that gets encoded in order to avoid duplicating information. If you look at the five countries in the example above after encoding with drop_first=True there are only four columns for China, India, Indonesia and the USA. The column for Brasil has been dropped because the information is already implicitly encoded, e.g. if the country is not any of the other four then it is Brasil. Failing to remove the redundant column can cause a problem in multiple regression models.

Comment: Thank you @KRKirov